# Simplify java enum test

Tags: java, enums, simplification

Given the code:

```
@Test
  public void testEnum() {
    for (SomeEnum someEnum : SomeEnum.values()) {   
       // in case of no match: throw exception 
      OtherEnum.valueOf(someEnum.name());
    }}
```

I am thinking about how to simplify this expression by Vanilla Java or org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils. I tried some code with contains() but nothing was clearly better.

What is best practice?

Comment: Why? How much simpler do you expect that to get? And why on earth would you even attempt to convert one enum to another?

Comment: what about: Arrays.stream(SomeEnum.values()).map(Enum::name).forEach(OtherEnum::valueOf);

Comment: and what do u mean by 'convert' ?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to test?

Comment: @DerBenniAusA Well you're trying to convert `SomeEnum` to `OtherEnum`, which is very suspicious. I would say the whole test is unnecessary, and you have an extra enum that you should get rid of (if you intend to make sure both enums contain the same values).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson test if each of the enums of SomeEnum are available in OtherEnum

Comment: @Kayaman: no I need both enums. It is to verify different interfaces

Comment: Well, it really doesn't matter how you write that test code, as long as it works.

Comment: I think that test is fine as it is when you add some exception handling. Of course if you want to test the opposite you'll need another test