# java comparison of two enums

Tags: java, enums, comparison

Given the test code:

```
@Test
  public void testEnumAreEqual() {
    for (var someEnum : SomeEnum.values()) {
      Assertions.assertTrue(EnumUtils.isValidEnum(OtherEnum.class, someEnum.name()));
    }
    for (var otherEnum : OtherEnum.values()) {
      Assertions.assertTrue(EnumUtils.isValidEnum(SomeEnum.class, otherEnum.name()));
    }
  }
```

I want to check if two given enums are containing the same values.

Is there maybe a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check whether `enum E1 { A, B; }` and `enum E2 { A, B; }` are equal because they both have the values A and B?

Comment: @Thomas: correct, yes

Comment: @SMA should not work, different instances

Comment: Why did you duplicate your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538546/simplify-java-enum-test)? People tried to help you in that question but you choose to ignore that help and post a new question instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build a set of the names:

```
Set<String> someEnumNames = 
    Arrays.stream(SomeEnum.values())
        .map(Enum::name)
        .collect(toSet());
```

Do the same for `OtherEnum` (consider extracting the above into a method).

Then:

```
assertEquals(someEnumNames, otherEnumNames);
```